# std::chrono & Boost.Units

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, c++-chrono, boost-units

I'm working on a software design in which I'd like to leverage `Boost.Units`. Some of the units I'd like to use represent time, however, I'm inclined to use the C++11 `std::chrono` units for those since they're standard.

I'm wondering if there's any clean integration between `Boost.Units` and `chrono` or whether I have to resort to writing my own converters and lose type safety by just copying scalar values between the types.

Are there any best practices for this issue?

Comment: I recently started working with `boost::units`. AFAICT there is no relation to time or `boost::chrono` there. I think the concepts behind `boost::units` and `boost::chrono` differ too much. However you could have a look to `boost::date_time` which builds on (.. or re-implements) `std::chrono`. There you'll find a plethora of classes that deal with any thinkable aspect of time.

Comment: Perhaps wrap the scalar in a new class, thus obscuring the scalar while providing `getAs[Type]` functions? One point of failure is better than many.

Comment: For those that come here the following question is relevant, but slightly different: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910373/interoperability-between-boostdate-time-and-stdchrono

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to convert a `std::chrono` duration to a boost time quantity you can use the following template function:

```
using time_quantity = boost::units::quantity<si::time, double>;

template<class _Period1, class _Type>
time_quantity toBoostTime( chrono::duration<_Type, _Period1> in)
{
  return time_quantity::from_value(double(in.count()) * double(_Period1::num) / double(_Period1::den) );
}
```

One thing to note is that the returned `time_quantity` will always be in seconds and the storage type will be of type double. If any of those two are a problem, the template can be adapted.

Example:

```
namespace bu = boost::units;
namespace sc = std::chrono;
using time_quantity_ms = bu::quantity<decltype(bu::si::milli * bu::si::second), int32_t>;

std::cout << "Test 1: " << toBoostTime(sc::seconds(10)) << std::endl;
std::cout << "Test 2: " << toBoostTime(sc::milliseconds(10)) << std::endl;
std::cout << "Test 3: " << static_cast<time_quantity_ms>(toBoostTime(sc::milliseconds(10))) << std::endl;

/* OUTPUT */
Test 1: 10 s
Test 2: 0.01 s
Test 3: 10 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a perfect answer, but boost::chrono provides an example of how to integrate it with a units system they define in the [example itself (devel)](https://github.com/boostorg/chrono/blob/develop/example/time2_demo.cpp) ([version at time of writing](https://github.com/boostorg/chrono/blob/30e3a2b9d934e244b2fc3bae5662b6ff04d007c2/example/time2_demo.cpp)).

Essentially, based on the [boost.units examples for quaternion and complex numbers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_units/Examples.html#boost_units.Examples.UDTExample) it should be possible to define the same functions for the std::chrono units, though it may require additional code for new user-defined units.

There is also a similar, though slightly different [question regarding boost::date_time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910373/interoperability-between-boostdate-time-and-stdchrono) which may also have useful information.

Sorry this isn't a full answer, but perhaps it will be a start someone else can complete!