# Sort JSON object by 2nd level field value

Tags: c++

Given the following code based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/33048253/1163457

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include "json.hpp"

using json = nlohmann::ordered_json;

int main() {
    json j = R"({"321":{"name":"Bar"},"123":{"name":"Foo"}})"_json;

    std::cout << "Original:\n" << j << '\n';

    std::sort(j.begin(), j.end(), [](const json a, const json b) {
        return a["name"].get<std::string>().compare(b["name"].get<std::string>()) < 0;
    });

    std::cout << "Sorted:\n" << j << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Results in the following runtime error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_2::detail::invalid_iterator'
  what():  [json.exception.invalid_iterator.209] cannot use offsets with object iterators
```

The only difference here is that there's no array.
How to sort the elements by name?

Expected output should be:

```
Original:
{"123":{"name":"Foo"},"321":{"name":"Bar"}}
Sorted:
{"321":{"name":"Bar"},"123":{"name":"Foo"}}
```

Comment: json is unordered... Wonder why you want to sort it...

Comment: yes because you are trying to use `std::sort` on a JSON object instead of a `JSON` array and `JSON` objects do not have a defined order, so you cannot sort them directly.

Comment: I'm iterating over the elements to add a list item in the GUI. And this should be sorted by name.

Comment: You might sort your gui components instead...

Comment: @Jarod42 Not sure if that's possible with the UI lib I use: https://github.com/HamletDuFromage/borealis I don't think so. But I'll probably end up re-structuring my json instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can convert the JSON object into a JSON array, sort the array, and then convert it back into a JSON object!

check this out

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include "json.hpp"

using json = nlohmann::ordered_json;

int main() {
    json j = R"({"321":{"name":"Bar"},"123":{"name":"Foo"}})"_json;

    std::cout << "Original:\n" << j << '\n';

    json jsonArray;
    for (auto& element : j.items()) {
        jsonArray.push_back(element.value());
    }

    std::sort(jsonArray.begin(), jsonArray.end(), [](const json& a, const json& b) {
        return a["name"].get<std::string>() < b["name"].get<std::string>();
    });

    json sortedObject;
    for (const auto& element : jsonArray) {
        sortedObject[element["name"].get<std::string>()] = element;
    }

    std::cout << "Sorted:\n" << sortedObject << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will lose some information: `{"Bar":{"name":"Bar"},"Foo":{"name":"Foo"}}`. But I may re-structure my json into an array instead so I can sort it.

Comment: That can't be compiled: `hello.cpp:15:38: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_2::basic_json<nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_2::ordered_map> > >::push_back(const nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_2::detail::iteration_proxy_value<nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_2::detail::iter_impl<nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_2::basic_json<nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_2::ordered_map> > >&)’`

Comment: Nope. Still a bunch of errors. Nevermind, I re-structured my json now as an array. If you mind to fix your code I'll accept it once it's working.