# Confused about the usual C++ solution to convert a date string from UTC to localtime

Tags: c++, datetime, c++17

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42855305/1794803), there's:

```
int main()
{
   std::string strUTCTime = "2017-03-17T13:20:00Z";
   std::wstring wstrUTCTime = std::wstring(strUTCTime.begin(),strUTCTime.end());
   time_t utctime = getEpochTime(wstrUTCTime.c_str());
   struct tm tm;
   /*Convert UTC TIME To Local TIme*/
   localtime_s(&tm, &utctime);
   char CharLocalTimeofUTCTime[30];
   strftime(CharLocalTimeofUTCTime, 30, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", &tm);
   string strLocalTimeofUTCTime(CharLocalTimeofUTCTime);
   std::cout << "\n\nLocal To UTC Time Conversion:::" << strLocalTimeofUTCTime;
}

std::time_t getEpochTime(const std::wstring& dateTime) 
{

     /* Standard UTC Format*/
     static const std::wstring dateTimeFormat{ L"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ" };

     std::wistringstream ss{ dateTime };
     std::tm dt;
     ss >> std::get_time(&dt, dateTimeFormat.c_str()); // (1)

     /* Convert the tm structure to time_t value and return Epoch. */
     return _mkgmtime(&dt);
}
```

I have doubts from the very beginning of the solution, and I ask this in a different question BECAUSE that solution is representative of multiple similar solutions out there: relying first on `get_time`, and afterwards on `mktime`.

My understanding of the situation is (looking at line `(1)`):

- The default locale imbued on any `stringstream` is the one corresponding to the machine (e.g., the local time).
- `get_time` parses its "input" taking into account the locale imbued on the stream; in other words: it thinks the parsed string is a time point, expressed in the given format, according to the "local calendar"; but IT'S NOT, it's an UTC date (from the "UTC" timezone)!

Isn't there any semantic problem with this, parsing an UTC datetime THINKING it's a local datetime? I really don't understand how is that "logical mismatch" solved. It makes no sense to me.

**NOTE:** For those recomending me alternatives to this solution (although that's not my question), I can't use C++20. I can use up to C++17, and also any POSIX and/or linux-specific function (gcc 8.5, Linux kernel 3.x).

Comment: The problem with looking for solutions online is that you mostly will find legacy ("C" style) examples.  C++ has the <chrono> header for anything related to time. Also see this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68556057/can-stdchronofrom-stream-convert-string-to-time-point-with-microseconds-accu

Comment: @PepijnKramer I can't use C++20, and from_stream is a C++20 function. I will add that note to the question.

Comment: Yes that is useful information, just tag the C++ version you need. E.g C++11, C++14 or C++17. There is also this date/time library : https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date that you might use

Comment: The trailing `Z` character in your `dateTimeFormat` indicates UTC == GMT time zone. Thus if all your input strings have a trailing Z, then they are in UTC.

Answer (score 2):

`getEpochTime` in the question works correctly with respect to time zones. There is no actual discrepancy between UTC and local time. Also it works correctly no matter what the current locale is.

Some more details:

- The `dateTimeFormat` value `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"` in the question is the longer [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, like `date + "T" + time + time_zone`, where the hardcoded `time_zone` string `"Z"` indicates time zone UTC == GMT.
- `std::get_time(...)` doesn't understand what `"Z"` means, and it doesn't understand time zones. It just blindly checks for character matches between the input and the format (i.e. that the input ends with `"Z"`), and it parses and populates output fields at conversion specifiers (starting with `"%"` in `dateTimeFormat`).
- The `ss >> std::get_time(..., dateTimeFormat)` call accepts UTC strings only (ending with `"Z"`, as specified in `dateTimeFormat`), in the longer ISO 8601 format (as specified in `dateTimeFormat`). Its output struct `std::tz` doesn't contain any field indicating a time zone.
- The `ss >> std::get_time(..., dateTimeFormat)` call respects the current locale when it parses month and weekday names (e.g. `"%b"`, `"%h"` and `"%B"` conversion specifiers accept `October` in the input string if the locale is English, and they accept `Oktober` instead if the locale is German). However, the specified `dateTimeFormat` doesn't use any locale-specific conversion specifiers, so that particular call is locale-independent.
- The `ss >> std::get_time(..., dateTimeFormat)` call ignores time zones.
- After the `ss >> std::get_time(&dt, dateTimeFormat)` call, the `dt` struct (of `std::tm`) will have the 6 fields (year, month, date, hour, minute, second) populated. (Maybe other fields also get populated.)
- The `_mkgmtime(&dt);` call converts the 6 fields of the `std::dt`, assuming the input is time zone UTC == GMT, to a [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), which is a signed integer of type `time_t`. Unix timestamps are independent of time zones, because they count the number of seconds since the Unix epoch (1970-01-01, start of day).

Please note that your call `strftime(CharLocalTimeofUTCTime, 30, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", &tm);` is incorrect, because it generates the trailing string `"Z"`, falsely indicating that the time zone is UTC. To fix it, drop the `Z`, thus [indicating local time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Local_time_(unqualified)) according to ISO 8601.

Please note that `getEpochTime` should be changed so that it checks for errors, like this:

- Check that `get_time` has succeeded (e.g. by checking `ss.good()`).
- Read 1 more character (e.g. by `ss.get()`), and check for EOF: on success, it must be present.
- Check that `_mkgmtime` has succeeded, at least by doing the reverse transformation with `gmtime`, and checking that the 6 fields are equal.
- If any errors have been found, indicate that to the caller.

Please note that the `_mkgmtime` function is Windows-specific. If your system doesn't have it, here is an implementation for both C and C++:

```
/* Converts a Gregorian civil date-time tuple in GMT (UTC) time zone to a
 * Unix timestamp (number of seconds since the beginning of 1970 CE).
 *
 * There is no similar standard C or POSIX function.
 *
 * Windows libc has the _mkgmtime function, doing the same as this
 * function, except that it also changes tm->tm_wday and tm->tm_yday.
 *
 * This reference implementation (without optimizations) works, and doesn't
 * overflow for any sizeof(time_t), as long as the result fits. It doesn't
 * check for overflow/underflow. It assumes that that time_t is signed.
 *
 * This is similar to the POSIX formula
 * (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_15),
 * but the latter uses tm->tm_yday instead.
 * The formula is: tm_sec + tm_min*60 + tm_hour*3600 +
 * tm_yday*86400 + (tm_year-70)*31536000 + ((tm_year-69)/4)*86400 -
 * ((tm_year-1)/100)*86400 + ((tm_year+299)/400)*86400.
 */
#include <time.h>
typedef char assert_int_is_at_least_32_bits[sizeof(int) >= 4 ? 1 : -1];
time_t fallback_mkgmtime(const struct tm *tm) {
  int year = tm->tm_year + 1900;
  int month = tm->tm_mon + 1;
  int yday;
  time_t y4, y100;
  if (month <= 2) {
    --year;
    month += 12;
  }
  yday = (153 * month + 3) / 5 + tm->tm_mday - 398;
  y4 = year >> 2;
  y100 = y4 / 25;
  if (y4 % 25 < 0) --y100;  /* Fix quotient if y4 was negative. */
  return (365 * (time_t)year + y4 - y100 + (y100 >> 2) + (yday - 719163)) *
      86400 + (tm->tm_hour * 60 + tm->tm_min) * 60 + tm->tm_sec;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the point I didn't understood is that the `get_time` is locale-independent in terms of calendar, but I think your indication about the `Z` is irrelevant here (it can be confusing for somewhere else reading it). `get_time` doesn't understand what "Z" means, so it won't use that information to change the interpretation of the input. I understand now that it only cares about "where are the numbers" (pure parsing), and fill `tm` in a carbon-copy fashion, and the locale, as you said, is only to interpret months names and such in case they appear.

Comment: I've extended my answer about how `std::get_time` understands `"Z"`, based on your comment.

Comment: `where the hardcoded time_zone string "Z" indicates time zone UTC == GMT`. Humans know Z indicates UTC, not `get_time`. In other words, if you remove `Z` from the string format (so that get_time ends parsing at the seconds), everything will work the same. That `Z` is not what helps `get_time` to know that the input is UTC, it just doesn't care: for it, it's only a char that you claim belongs to the input, like `scanf` does: if the input matches the format, the parsing succeeds.

Comment: Indeed, my extended answer now explicitly explains this (`"Z"`), so there is no confusion I know of. However, removing `"Z"` from the end of the format does change the success of the parsing (if there is no `"Z"` on the input) and also the stream position. However, since `getEpochTime` doesn't check for any of these, there is no visible difference. I've added a secton about error checking to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> **NOTE:** For those recomending me alternatives to this solution (although that's not my question), I can't use C++20. I can use up to C++17, and also any POSIX and/or linux-specific function (gcc 8.5, Linux kernel 3.x).

Ok, here's an alternative which has much simpler syntax, works with C++17, and will easily port to C++20 when that becomes available to you in the future.

It does use a [free, open-source, 3rd party library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) of which I am the author, and 24h support team (free support too!).

```
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
   std::string strUTCTime = "2017-03-17T13:20:00Z";
   date::sys_seconds utctime;
   std::istringstream in{strUTCTime};
   in >> date::parse("%FT%TZ", utctime);
   auto loctime = date::current_zone()->to_local(utctime);
   auto strLocalTimeofUTCTime = date::format("%FT%T", loctime);
   std::cout << "\n\nUTC To Local Time Conversion:::" << strLocalTimeofUTCTime << '\n';
}
```

I tried to use your existing variable names to help make the code more readable to you.  And I dropped the trailing "Z" from the local time string as correctly recommended in the other answer.

For me the output of this program is:

```
UTC To Local Time Conversion:::2017-03-17T09:20:00
```

My computer's local UTC offset is currently -5h.  The gitHub repo has make files.  Sadly, ignore them.  Here is how I built this program:

```
g++ -std=c++17 test.cpp -I../date/include ../date/src/tz.cpp -DUSE_OS_TZDB
```

I.e. just compile with the date lib's tz.cpp source file.  On Linux you may also have to add `-lpthread` if the pthread library isn't automatically linked in.

The `-DUSE_OS_TZDB` flag tells the date library to use the IANA database that ships with your Linux system.  This is simpler than downloading the IANA database (which is another option).

Unlike the C solution, this solution can also be trivially altered to ignore your computer's locally set time zone and instead use another. To do so change:

```
auto loctime = date::current_zone()->to_local(utctime);
```

To (for example):

```
auto loctime = date::locate_zone("Pacific/Auckland")->to_local(utctime);
```

and the output will change to:

```
UTC To Local Time Conversion:::2017-03-18T02:20:00
```

When the time comes to port this to C++20, (and thus drop dependence on my date library) it is simply:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
   std::string strUTCTime = "2017-03-17T13:20:00Z";
   std::chrono::sys_seconds utctime;
   std::istringstream in{strUTCTime};
   in >> std::chrono::parse("%FT%TZ", utctime);
   auto loctime = std::chrono::current_zone()->to_local(utctime);
   auto strLocalTimeofUTCTime = std::format("{:%FT%T}", loctime);
   std::cout << "\n\nUTC To Local Time Conversion:::" << strLocalTimeofUTCTime << '\n';
}
```

[Demo.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Tkd99bPuQecvgALu)

And so your code is not only simpler and more flexible, but future-proofed as well.