# std::get_time on Visual 2015 does not fail on incorrect date

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, std

I'm executing the following code on Windows with Visual Studio 2015. Basically I use `std::get_time` to parse a date, but when the date is invalid, for example, a day greater than 31, it does not seem to set the fail bit on the stream.

I have tried this on Ubuntu with g++ 5.4.0 and it sets the fail bit and prints "Parsing failed!". Is this a bug on Windows or am I doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance!

```
std::string date = "2019-2-37 23:00:00"; // day (37) is wrong. 
std::string format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S";
std::tm tm_object{};
std::istringstream input(date);        
input.imbue(std::locale(std::setlocale(LC_ALL, nullptr)));
input >> std::get_time(&tm_object, format.c_str());
if (input.fail()) 
{
    std::cout << "Parsing failed!";
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Parsing ok!\n";
    std::cout << "Day is : " << tm_object.tm_mday;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Howard Hinnant's free, open-source header-only datetime library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) on Windows to give you the desired behavior.  The syntax is only slightly different, and it is much easier to use, and compatible with `<chrono>`.  It is also better documented and specified than the time-parsing parts of the C++ standard.

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int
main()
{
    std::string date = "2019-2-37 23:00:00"; // day (37) is wrong. 
    std::string format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S";
    date::sys_seconds tm_object{};
    std::istringstream input(date);        
    input >> date::parse(format, tm_object);
    if (input.fail()) 
    {
        std::cout << "Parsing failed!";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Parsing ok!\n";
        date::year_month_day ymd = date::floor<date::days>(tm_object);
        std::cout << "Day is : " << ymd.day();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Parsing failed!
```

This library also works with g++ 5.4.0 and clang.

You can also simplify your `format` down to `"%F %T"`, and it can also work with subsecond precision if desired.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Howard, your library works for me!
Anyway I still don't understand why there is no a strptime function for Windows or why std::get_time does not verify the dates are correct on Visual 2015.

Comment: @rboc:  Glad it worked for you!  `strptime` is not standard C++, but specified by POSIX.  Though `std::get_time` is specified in terms of `strptime`.  POSIX says this about `strptime`:  "No errors are defined." (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html)

Comment: Yes, but at least strptime returns a null pointer on unsuccessful completion (February 37th). I expected to std::get_time to do something similar on Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: @rboc:  I am trying to get my library standardized.  I will try to get a more precise specification into the standard.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the world of the grey zone of the standard! `std::get_time` (various overloads) is specified in chapters 22 Localization library, and 27 Input/output library of the standard.

AFAIK, the standard requires:

- if the input string correctly describes a valid date in valid format, the `std::tm` object is populated accordingly
- if the input string cannot be parsed, the fail bit on the input string shall be set

But here, the input string can be parsed, and some implementations can assume that the march 32 is just the april 1. Said differently it is unspecified by standard what controls an implementation shall do on the input value. A non numeric day shall give an error, but this is implementation dependant.

Comment: I thought that on 37th of February it should set the fail bit. :-)

Comment: @rboc: That's the job of a calendar library, not an I/O library.  Make a copy of your `struct tm`, call `mktime()` on one copy, and then compare.  If the date was invalid, `mktime()` will have made changes to "correct" it, and you can detect that change.