# How to get difference between two times using date library?

Tags: c++, date

I`m using [date library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html). I didn`t understand how to get difference between 2 time points in milliseconds?

```
date::time_of_day<std::chrono::milliseconds> time1;
date::time_of_day<std::chrono::milliseconds> time2;
// set some time...
auto diff = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(time2 - time1);
std::cout << diff.count() << " milliseconds" << std::endl;
```

Error:

> no match for 'operator-' (operand types are 'date::time_of_day<std::chrono::duration<long long int, std::ratio<1, 1000> > >' {aka 'date::hh_mm_ss<std::chrono::duration<long long int, std::ratio<1, 1000> > >'} and 'date::time_of_day<std::chrono::duration<long long int, std::ratio<1, 1000> > >' {aka 'date::hh_mm_ss<std::chrono::duration<long long int, std::ratio<1, 1000> > >'})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Late during the standardization process, `time_of_day` was renamed to `hh_mm_ss`.  The `time_of_day` name still exists as a type alias to `hh_mm_ss` in `date` as a backwards compatibility helper.

`hh_mm_ss<milliseconds>` is just a `{hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds}` data structure that is handy for getting the "fields" out of a `milliseconds` duration.  This is especially useful for formatting.  But it is not that useful as an arithmetic type (such as subtraction).

To do arithmetic, it is best to operate with durations (e.g. `milliseconds`) and time_points (e.g. `sys_time<milliseconds>`).  For example:

```
auto time1 = sys_days{July/2/2021} + 12h + 15min + 3s + 45ms;
auto time2 = sys_days{July/2/2021} + 13h + 15min + 4s + 145ms;
auto diff = time2 - time1;
cout << diff << '\n';
```

Output:

```
3601100ms
```

In the above example, `time1` and `time2` have type `date::sys_time<std::chrono::milliseconds>` which itself is a type alias for `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::milliseconds>`.  And `diff` has type `std::chrono::milliseconds`.

Comment: How to convert existing `hh_mm_ss<milliseconds>` variable to `sys_time<milliseconds>`?

Comment: `hh_mm_ss<milliseconds>` can be converted to the _duration_ `milliseconds` with explicit conversion syntax:  `milliseconds x{hms};`.  This will just be the sum of the fields within the `hh_mm_ss`.  Then, if you really want to, you can convert that duration to a time_point with the same explicit conversion syntax:  `sys_time<milliseconds> tp{x};`.  Note that this time point will have the value of `x` `milliseconds` after 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 UTC (assuming `x` is positive).

Comment: For handling "times without dates" see this post for different options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64895694/576911