# Chrono, c++, comparing dates

Tags: c++, time, compare, c++-chrono

I have Problem with comparing dates from chrono library.
For example, something should happen when the date_to_do_something is matched with the current date.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono> 
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

int main(){
 end = chrono::system_clock::now();
 string date_to_do_something ="Tue Jul 27 17:13:17 2021";  
 time_t end_time = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(end);
 //gives some weird types:pc, pl
 cout<<typeid(ctime(&end_time)).name()<<endl;
 cout<<typeid(&end_time).name()<<endl;
 //Now how to compare?
 
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse a date string into a c++11 std::chrono time\_point or similar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021388/how-to-parse-a-date-string-into-a-c11-stdchrono-time-point-or-similar)

Comment: What should happen if Jul 27, 2021 isn't a Monday?

Comment: It doesnt matter I just gave an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `pc` and `pl` types are types `char*` and `long*`. If you want to print the full type name using `typeid` pipe your output to `c++filt`, something like `./prog | c++filt --types`.
To compare these two dates, you should convert `std::string` to `time_t`. For that use `tm structure`. To convert string to time use `strptime()` function from `time.h` header. After that create `time_point` value using `from_time_t()` and `mktime()`. And at the end convert `time_point_t` type to `time_t` with `to_time_t()` function.

Your code should be something like this:

```
  auto end = chrono::system_clock::now();
  string date_to_do_something = "Mon Jul 27 17:13:17 2021";
  time_t end_time = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(end);
  // gives some weird types:pc, pl
  cout << typeid(ctime(&end_time)).name() << endl;
  cout << typeid(&end_time).name() << endl;
  // Now how to compare?
  tm t = tm{};
  strptime(date_to_do_something.c_str(), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y", &t);
  chrono::system_clock::time_point tp =
      chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(mktime(&t));
  time_t time = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(tp);
  if (time == end_time) {
    // do something
  } else {
    // do something else
  }
```