# boost: How to sleep current thread until given ptime?

Tags: c++, boost

Not sure if I'm missing something, but how can I pass a `boost::posix_time::ptime` object to `boost::this_thread::sleep_until()`? More specifically: How can I convert from `boost::posix_time::ptime` to `boost::chrono::time_point`?

```cpp
void do_magic( const boost::posix_time::ptime& wakeup_time )
{
    boost::this_thread::sleep_until( wakeup_time ); // not working

    do_more_magic();
}
```

I'm using boost version `1.62`, if that is of any relevance.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are not using `std` instead of boost? If you are constraint in the C++ version, you should probably add the correct version tag.

Comment: @walnut all the code around is using `boost::posix_time`. I don't want to change the whole code base. Converting to `std` could be an option, though.

Comment: If `std::this_thread::sleep_until` is fine as well, then I guess [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910373/interoperability-between-boostdate-time-and-stdchrono) might be a (almost?) duplicate. It should also be adjustable to the boost variant, but maybe there is a simpler mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meantime, this problem has been solved with the `deadline_timer`. There is a solution in [`boost::asio`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/deadline_timer.html):

```
// Construct a timer without setting an expiry time.
boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(my_context);

// Set an expiry time relative to now.
timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(5));

// Wait for the timer to expire.
timer.wait();
```